# Image rotated when chosen from gallery

Tags: android

I am using the following code to get the orientation of the selected image so that if it was taken vertically, when selected from gallery it would not be shown horizontally.

The error is occuring in the
File imageFile = new File(selectedImage.toString()); in the parameter selectedImage.toString()) since when I changed the initial int rotate=90 and chose a vertical image the result was good.

Am I passing the parameter to the File correct?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_SELECTED) {
        try {
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
            stream.close();
            //orientation
            try {
                int rotate = 0;
                try {
                    File imageFile = new File(selectedImage.toString());
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                            imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            rotate = 270;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            rotate = 180;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            rotate = 90;
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                yourSelectedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourSelectedImage , 0, 0, yourSelectedImage.getWidth(), yourSelectedImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);  }
            catch (Exception e) {}
            //end of orientation

            imgButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imgButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image was not selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Add this line in your Manifest inside your activity in which the image is opening gallery  like this    <activity
            android:name=".ui.ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: Did that code help a bit ?

Comment: No, errors: android:configChanges and screenOrientation are not allowed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    BitmapFactory.Options options;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_SELECTED) {
        try {
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
            String mImagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
            stream.close();
            //orientation
            try {
                int rotate = 0;
                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                            mImagePath);
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            rotate = 270;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            rotate = 180;
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            rotate = 90;
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                yourSelectedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourSelectedImage , 0, 0, yourSelectedImage.getWidth(), yourSelectedImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);  }
            catch (Exception e) {}
            //end of orientation

            imgButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imgButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image was not selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked it as a correct answer. I can't vote since I need a reputation of 15 first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for image handling compile picasso is best library using it you can easily handle images using it you can load image from cache also and increase performance of your app so try to avoid doing lots of code and add following line in your build gradle and then use picasso in your code.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

Comment: using picasso doesn't solve the problem, the image is still rotated